# How do a reset last window size/position?

Tags: uwp-xaml, template10

I have a UWP-XAML app that uses Template10 and has a bug in window sizing the *first* time the app is run. After running the app, the window in question appears in a weird location, then the windows resizes itself and finally when the app stops, Windows remembers the window's last size and position. The next time the app is run, the saved size and position are restored.

How can I reset this saved size/position data so I can see how my app behaves as if it is running for the first time?

I'd really like to do this programmatically if possible so I can reset as needed easily.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have your issues been resolved? And do you have any other updates?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `PreferredLaunchViewSize` in your `App.xaml.cs` `App_VisibleBoundsChanged` delegate method likes code behind. When you open the app again, it will reset the last windows size.

```cs
 protected override  void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
 {
     Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;  

     ......

     if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
     {
         if (rootFrame.Content == null)
         {         
             rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
         }      
         Window.Current.Activate();
         ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged += App_VisibleBoundsChanged;
     }
 }

 private void App_VisibleBoundsChanged(ApplicationView sender, object args)
 {
     var bounds = sender.VisibleBounds;
     var scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
     var size = new Size(bounds.Width * scaleFactor, bounds.Height * scaleFactor);
     ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = size;
     ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;         
 }
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Please remember that the developer can request a resize but it is not guaranteed depending on the device and the mode of the current environment.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Thank you for your supplement.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Where can I look for, to know about what are the limitations depending on the device or mode of environment? I would like to know how & why these 2, affect my resize request.